# Java 8 Instant class not have plusHours method despite shown in Oracle Tutorial example code

Tags: java, java-time

The [*Oracle Tutorial* page for the `Instant` class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/instant.html) shows this example code:

```
Instant oneHourLater = Instant.now().plusHours(1);
```

When I try to compile this code, the compiler throws the error:

- **Error**

```
InstantPrint.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        Instant oneHourLater = Instant.now().plusHours(1);
                                            ^
  symbol:   method plusHours(int)
  location: class Instant
```

But this Java documentation mentions `plusHours()` method, but I check this `Instant` class and it doesn't contain `plusHours()` method.

Thereafter, why mention this `plusHours()` method in the example?

Comment: link is not found. There is no such method https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html

Comment: Have you considered trying [`Instant#plus(long, TemporalUnit`)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#plus-long-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-)

Comment: check again @Ravi

Comment: okay I will check your example @MadProgrammer

Comment: @AK.Sharma I think, you better check. Either my ctrl+f is not working or you are looking some where

Comment: And yes, the tutorial is wrong :/

Comment: **Down-voters:** Notice this Question discovered faulty example code in the official Oracle Tutorial. A worthy Question indeed.

Answer (score 61):

## The *Oracle Tutorial* is incorrect

Unfortunately, the *Oracle Tutorial* is incorrect on this matter. That line of example code is simply wrong. Good catch on your part.

This error is quite unfortunate as the Tutorial is otherwise a fine resource for learning and studying Java.

### `Instant::plus`

The [`Instant`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class has no such method as `plusHours` defined in either Java 8 or Java 9.

Instead, you can call the [`plus`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#plus-long-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-) method, and specify hours.

```
Instant later = instant.plus( 1 , ChronoUnit.HOURS ) ;
```

### `ZonedDateTime::plusHours`

The [`Instant`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class is a basic building-block class, indicating a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Usually when performing manipulations such as adding hours, you’ll likely want to account for anomalies such as [Daylight Saving Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time), and so you will care about [time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_zone). For that, use the [`ZonedDateTime`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) class. That class *does* offer a convenient [`plusHours`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html#plusHours-long-) method, a likely source of the confusion for the *Tutorial* authors.

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter abbreviation such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ; // Same moment, but viewed through the lens of a region’s wall-clock time.
ZonedDateTime zdtLater = zdt.plusHours( 1 ) ;
```

## `Instant` versus `ZonedDateTime`

Let's look at an example of an anomaly in adding hours. When zoned, we add an hour to the particular moment of 1 AM on March 23, 2017 and of course expect 2 AM, but we are surprised to see 3 AM. Yet when we consider the very same moment in UTC rather than that particular time zone, the very same point on the timeline, adding an hour behaves as expected.

This particular anomaly is due to the adoption of [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) in most of North America, in particular here, the time zone [`America/New_York`](https://time.is/New_York). In the Spring, the clocks "spring-forward" an hour. As the clocks strike 2 AM, they jump to 3 AM. So the hour of two o’clock never existed on that day.

```
// ZonedDateTime
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2017 , Month.MARCH , 12 ) ;
LocalTime lt = LocalTime.of( 1 , 0 ) ;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/New_York" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( ld , lt , z ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdtOneHourLater = zdt.plusHours( 1 ) ;

System.out.println( "zdt: " + zdt ) ;
System.out.println( "zdtOneHourLater: " + zdtOneHourLater ) ; 
System.out.println( "Yikes! 1 AM plus an hour is 3 AM? Yes, that is an anomaly known as Daylight Saving Time (DST)." ) ;
System.out.println( "" ) ;

// Instant
Instant instant = zdt.toInstant() ;  // Adjust into UTC. Same moment, same point on the timeline, but viewed by a different wall-clock.
Instant instantOneHourLater = instant.plus( 1 , ChronoUnit.HOURS ) ;

System.out.println( "instant: " + instant ) ;
System.out.println( "instantOneHourLater: " + instantOneHourLater ) ;  
System.out.println( "Instant is always in UTC. So no anomalies, no DST. Adding an hour to 1 AM results in 2 AM every time." ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/MILrXx).

> zdt: 2017-03-12T01:00-05:00[America/New_York]
>
> zdtOneHourLater: 2017-03-12T03:00-04:00[America/New_York]
>
> Yikes! 1 AM plus an hour is 3 AM? Yes, that is an anomaly known as Daylight Saving Time (DST).
>
> instant: 2017-03-12T06:00:00Z
>
> instantOneHourLater: 2017-03-12T07:00:00Z
>
> Instant is always in UTC. So no anomalies, no DST. Adding an hour to 1 AM results in 2 AM every time.

Comment: @AK.Sharma @Ravi **That Tutorial page is incorrect**, both according to the JavaDoc of the `Instant` class and according to actual practice using Java 8 Update 144 (I just tested this now). I would suggest filing a bug report, but that warning at the top of the pages gives me the sickly feeling that Oracle is giving up on maintaining the Tutorial.

Comment: "The Instant class is a basic building-block class, indicating a moment on the timeline in UTC. "
That statement is incorrect, how moment in time can be in UTC?

Comment: @abc667 An `Instant` is by definition a count of seconds plus fractional second since the epoch reference moment of the first moment of 1970 in UTC. So an `Instant` is always a moment in UTC. Accordingly, the `toString` method generates a string representing the date and time-of-day in UTC. Read the [class documentation](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) for trivial details irrelevant to practical use in business-oriented apps.

Comment: both `instant.plus(1, ChronoUnit.HOURS)` and `zdt.plushHours(1)` return time corresponding to the same time instance ([`later.equals(zdtLater.toInstant())`](https://ideone.com/MO4UnY))

Comment: @jfs True, but I'm not sure of your point. A ZonedDateTime is just an Instant with an assigned time zone. Adding an hour to either results in the same moment on the timeline.

Comment: @BasilBourque your answer implies  that ZonedDateTime produces a different result (“account for anomalies...”) while you agree that the result is the same time instance. It is unclear why would you mention ZonedDateTime here at all.

Comment: @jfs Added section on `Instant` versus `ZonedDateTime` to show you where adding an hour to 1 AM results in 3 AM rather than 2 AM. Most people would consider that an anomaly.

Comment: @BasilBourque to remind you: the question is about Instant class. Obviously ZonedDateTime is useful in general, I don't see why it is relevant for the current question. As I said above, the instant produces the exact same time instance.

Comment: @jfs You could just as well say the Question is about the `plusHours` method rather than the `Instant` class. The `ZonedDateTime` class does offer that method. Pointing out this fact serves to explain the mistake by the authors of the Tutorial who otherwise did fine work. Sure the `ZonedDateTime` class could be omitted from this Answer, but including it illuminates the bigger picture.

Comment: check this link question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46903033/java-8-documentation-date-time-tutorials-mistake?noredirect=1#comment80752867_46903033 @Basil Bourque