# Java 8 documentation Date-time tutorials mistake

Tags: java, java-time, date

The [Oracle Tutorial page for the Temporal Query](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/iso/queries.html) show this example code.

**- Code**

```
TemporalQueries query = TemporalQueries.precision();
System.out.printf("LocalDate precision is %s%n",LocalDate.now().query(query));
```

When I compile this segment code, the Compiler throws the error: 

 **- Error**

```
TemporalQueryExample.java:8: error: incompatible types: TemporalQuery<TemporalUnit> cannot be converted to TemporalQueries
    TemporalQueries query = TemporalQueries.precision();
                                                     ^
TemporalQueryExample.java:10: error: no suitable method found for query(TemporalQueries)
                      LocalDate.now().query(query));
                                     ^
```

I don't know this java 8 documentation tutorial example is correct or not but I copy this code segment and paste my IDE then IDE throw the Error.

Comment: did you import these `import java.time.temporal.TemporalQuery;
import java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit;` ?

Comment: If you're asking whether there's a mistake, the answer is yes.

Comment: yes! i import this package @Lokesh

Comment: And the mistake is on this line `TemporalQueries query = TemporalQueries.precision();` change it to `TemporalQuery<TemporalUnit> query = TemporalQueries.precision();`

Comment: @Lokesh first you check this link example

Comment: @AK.Sharma what do you want me to look in the link ?

Comment: Yes ! please you check this link example @Lokesh

Comment: @AK.Sharma official site says `The Java Tutorials have been written for JDK 8. Examples and practices described in this page don't take advantage of improvements introduced in later releases.` I think the documentation is old. Any way you can report em You may have updated your java. Consider accepting the solution if helped in any way.

Comment: thanks! you understand my problem @Stultuske and #Lokesh

Answer (score 1):

Change this line `TemporalQueries query = TemporalQueries.precision();` to this `TemporalQuery<TemporalUnit> query = TemporalQueries.precision();`

You can check this Java 9 [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalQuery.html)

Answer (score 1):

There is an error in the code. Look at what Lokesh has mentioned.

To further learn coding, make sure you understand the error properly. It will make your life easier. In this example, the error says: `TemporalQuery<TemporalUnit>` cannot be converted to `TemporalQueries`

If you check your code, `<TemporalUnit>` is not there, which is an indication that you have to place it somewhere and the right place to have it is mentioned by Lokesh.

You can go through this [tutorial](http://java2s.com/Tutorials/Java/Data_Type_How_to/Date/Get_Temporal_Queries_precision.htm)

Comment: he IS going through tutorials, the official ones. They are (or at least, should be) a lot more dependable compared to those of java2s. If you re-read his post, you see that it's not just a "I don't get this", but rather a "I think there's a mistake in the original tutorial".

Comment: Agreed, I am just pointing him to the tutorial that I follow and am quite satisfied with it. More specifically, I agree that Java2s does not have too much to offer, but is good to explain the codes in an easy to understand language. I hope this makes sense.

Comment: sure, I understand, but the link you posted isn't even a tutorial, it's a snippet of code without the least of explanation about the how or what. sure, when copy pasting it, you'll get it to work, but understanding it isn't the same. 'easy to understand language' for tutorials usually means: "we left out a lot of the technical stuff, that you actually should know, but would make it difficult". not the best idea to promote that. but the question was not as much about the code, as it was about the (official) tutorial it was taken from/based upon.

Comment: @Hemang It is always recommended to follow their official documentation. Sure the internet is full of tutorials like this. But following the official means you are following the core from where it was begin.

Comment: No worries guys, I have no intentions to promote, but can remove that part if you guys suggest.

Comment: However, thanks for explaining the use of official tutorial. I completely understand the question was about a mistake in the tutorial but I mentioned it at the end, just so that he can go through other tutorials as well and not get stuck with the codes. The tip here was to know what the error speaks off and not the other way round.